# Multiple Gradle Projects within one Eclipse Project - Refresh Dependencies

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have roughly this project structure in eclipse:

```
rootproj
---settings.gradle
---build.gradle

eclipseProject
---folderA
------build.gradle
---folderB
------build.gradle
```

I declare folderA and folderB as gradle projects in settings.gradle.  folderA and folderB have a src/main/java with src files in them

Is there any way, in eclipse, I can right click on 'eclipseProject->gradle->refresh dependencies' and have folderA's and folderB's dependencies downloaded and added to 'eclipseProject's "Gradle Dependencies" folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I did it:

First, I needed to to make `eclipseProject` a gradle project by adding it to settings.gradle.  Then I needed to add a `build.gradle` file to `eclipseProject`.  And then in the `build.gradle` file in `eclipseProject`, I had to add these lines to configure the .classpath file that gets automatically generated when I right click `eclipseProject->gradle->refresh dependencies`:

```
eclipse.classpath.plusConfigurations += [
    project(':folderA').configurations.compile,
    project(':folderB').configurations.compile
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you import the projects individually or do you import the root project? Import the root project and you will get the sub projects listed individually.